# MiKTeX | Problem with the oberdiek Package

Tags: lyx, packages, miktex

I tried using `\centernot`, after reading that it uses the `oberdiek` package.
I went to MikTeX to ensure that it's installed, and found it, yet after right-clicking it, my operation system, Windows (10, 64-bit, MikTex is running on 32-bit), didn't tell me any information from which I can infer whether the package is installed or not - if it's installed, I can't uninstall it, and if it's not installed, I can't install it.

So, I don't know if I even have it not.

I'm using LyX, and it doesn't find it - when I include it in the Premables with `\usepackage{oberdiek}.
If it is not installed, why can't install it?

I can't use the package, and I don't know how to get it, if I don't have it.

Help would be much appreciated.

[image: Problamge image]

Comment: Your screenshot says "installed on 2016-12-06" so you have it. But it is not a single style that you can load in a document, it is a collection of styles. The package that you should load is `centernot`.

Comment: I tried loading both, first loading `oberdiek` and then loading `centernot` and LyX didn't recognize `oberdiek` (it didn't find it).

And if it's installed, why can't I uninstall it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) already mentioned in her comment, [oberdiek](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek) is a bundle of packages that the person [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) provides.

This is clear if you follow the [link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek) which leads to the following page:

[image]

So you cannot use something like `\usepackage{oberdiek}` but you can load one of the many packages that Heiko Oberdiek provides such as `\usepackage{cen­ter­not}`.

You can install and uninstall the bundle of package in MiKTeX as you can see in the following screesnhot:

[image]

> Maybe you need to synchronize with a/the repository if the uninstall
>   option is not available.

Comment: I tried doing it, at first, and I thought that it didn't work, because `\centernot \Rightarrow` didn't render as a full sign in LyX right away, but it works - thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll leave you some presents for your departure. I hope you'll connect from time to time. Come on, I'm near you. I wish you once again my regards and goodbye. See you soon, dearest.

Comment: @Sebastiano Much appreciated!